# Grails validation on Date 13 years ago from today

Tags: grails, groovy

I'm trying to set `dateOfBirth` on register to be a minimum of 13 years old. I don't want to have an `age` field on my User class, I want to just stick with `dateOfBirth`.

How do I include validation to subtract exactly 13 years, accounting for leap years.

Currently in my constraints I am using this line:

`dateOfBirth blank: false, max: (new Date() - 13*365)`

I would prefer not to use custom validation as I believe there must be a way without it. I've tried the following:

`dateOfBirth blank: false, use(TimeCategory) { max: new Date() - 13.year }`

- This doesn't work due to the `use(TimeCategory)` part (I believe)

I've also tried to use the magic numbers plugin to no avail. I tried:

`dateOfBirth blank: false, max: 13.years.ago`

and

`dateOfBirth blank: false, max: 13.years.ago.toDate()`

and imported `com.metasieve.magicnumbers.*` package.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4081169/grails-min-constraint-for-date-validation might help

Answer (score 2):

What's wrong with custom validators? I believe this is an excellent case where a custom validator is the right choice.

```
import groovy.time.TimeCategory    

dateOfBirth validator: {
    use (TimeCategory) {
        it?.before(13.years.ago) 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The fact that your first try works (though inexactly) leads me to believe that this would work:

```
dateOfBirth blank: false, max: ((new Date()).toCalendar().add( -13, Calendar.YEAR )).getTime()
```

Though I would check that this isn't actually compiled to a single date, but is recomputed every time the constraint is checked.